# Angularjs Modal + autocomplete input (Plunker attached)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete, modal-dialog

I have the following plunker attached herewith

http://plnkr.co/edit/3H2q4eVJW5h0K3EdJIBe?p=preview

```
<html>
</html>
```

As per the plunker, i have 3 issues which i am not able to fix.

1) When user clicks on 'add row', 3 input fields show up. 2,3 and 1. i want the sequence to be 1,2 and then 3. 1 is the autocomplete input box which should be at the top. If i bring 1 to top, i dont see 2 and 3 then.

2) Ok and Close buttons dont close. Am i doing anything wrong in the function ? Pressing 'ok' should let me retrieve the selected value at input 1. Pressing 'cancel' should close the modal

3) If you see $scope.fetchList, it has a JSON value. I want the $scope.fetchList to be using an array instead. What changes needs to be done in order to get the following. Just an example of autocomplete list items below.

```
$scope.fetchList = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0FsZEjowmVM0Abu272J?p=preview)

Here's how I addressed your issues:

**Issue 1**

I just wrapped your elements in div's

```
  <div>
    <div>
      <br> Select name:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <autocomplete placeholder="Enter sedol" style="width:29%" selection="selection" source="fetchList" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <br> Given Data1:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="text" readonly>
    </div>
    <div>
      <br> Given Data2:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="text" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Issue 2**

You hade the save an cancel functions declared in the parent controller rather than the controller for the modal, so I moved it.

**Issue 3**

I don't understand the issue.  fetchList() already returns an array albeit an array of objects rather than an array of strings.  Changing it to an array of string breaks all sorts of code in your directive.

Comment: @jbrown- for the 3rd issue, here is wat i am trying to do. Instead of those hard coded values, i am trying to get values from the database. so it would  be a different format than this here. it has an objectarray with id and name in it. The database value would be different. right ?

Comment: @Patrick - What you currently have on the client side is common for autocomplete.  I don't know specifically what is coming from your api (database) but I'd suspect that it either is or could be returned as an array of JSON objects.

Comment: @Jbrown- one last query, once i select autocomplete item and it gets updated in input '1', and i close the modal, how do i get the selected value ?

Comment: @Patrick - It can be handled in the promise $modal.open returns.  Give me just a minute and I will update the plunker.

Comment: @jbrown- did you get a chance to look at it ?

Comment: @Patrick - I've just spent the last few minutes looking at it and it won't be as easy as it should be.  Your approach of using jquery to accomplish this autocomplete makes it a tougher issue in terms of interacting with the data.  If you had gone with pure angular it would be as simple as binding the value to model using ngModel that would then be accessible on $scope of the modal controller and easily passed back to the view controller.

Comment: @Patrick -   Did you look at a pure angular solution before spinning up your own directive incorporating jquery?  You're already using ui-bootstrap which has a typeahead component that does what you are trying to do but plays nice with angular.

Comment: @jbrown- i didnt.  :( do you have a plunker so i can have a look at that ?

Comment: @Patrick - no but if you go to the docs (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and go to the TypeAhead section, there is a plunk there.

Comment: @jbrown- just saw. it is a basic typeahead. i was looking for using inside a modal..

Comment: @Patrick -  there's nothing unique to the usage for it whether it is in a modal or not.  It can be used in any view.

Comment: @jbrown- if you could show me a plunker using typehead and modal, it would be of great help.

Comment: @Patrick -  I don't have one and I don't have the time to create one.  If you wan't to fork your plunker, or create a new one,  and give it a try I will do what I can to help you.